# Is there an easy way to implement INSPIRE model in PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, database, inspire

I need to implement INSPIRE (Infrastructure for Spatial Information in the European Community) model in PostGIS.

I searched everywhere but couldn't find SQL file, or any other implementation that I could download. Is there any way to quickly auto generate empty tables with all relations, or do I have to manually generate 400+ tables?

Comment: That is the first time I have ever seen the words easy and Inspire in the same sentence :-). As to your question, no idea, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You don't say which INSPIRE [data model](http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/data-specifications/2892) you want to implement, but on a general note, yes it is possible.

For example if you wanted to implement the [Mineral Resources](https://inspire.ec.europa.eu/Themes/135/2892) model you could use the SQL provided by [The Minerals4EU Project](http://www.minerals4eu.eu/), there's details too of implementing a complex feature WFS using deegree.

```
http://data.geus.dk/svn/m4eu/09 DB M4EU/trunk/v1.1.x/v1.1.2
```

For other data models try posting a request on the [INSPIRE Thematic Clusters](https://themes.jrc.ec.europa.eu/) forum

Comment: I want to implement all 34 spatial data themes. If there is no database to download, are there any instructions on how to build my own from schema (and where to download all required files)?

Comment: There isn't a single data model though so it's unlikely you'll find a single download that'll do it all.  You'll need to approach each domain and ask independently if you want to use models those communities have implemented.

Answer (score 1):

As @nmtoken wrote, you don't need to write the SQL DDL by hand. With the [OSGeo Project deegree](https://www.deegree.org) a [command line tool](https://github.com/deegree/deegree3/tree/master/deegree-tools/deegree-tools-config) is provided, which can generate SQL DDL statements from INSPIRE data models (typically a GML Application Schema). For example the following command generates the SQL DDL for the INSPIRE data model Cadastral Parcels 4.0 (Annex 1):

`java -jar deegree-cli-utility.jar --srid=25832 --format=ddl --idtype=int http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/schemas/cp/4.0/CadastralParcels.xsd`

Check the provided documentation for more information. This command line tool is intended to be used with deegree web services but the generated tables may also be accessed with QGIS or other tools. So before you start, check what kind of tools you are going to use and what you need. You may have a look on [gdal driver GMLAS](https://www.gdal.org/drv_gmlas.html) too.

Further information how to setup a deegree web services with PostGIS is described in the [Quickstart Tutorial "INSPIRE Network Services with deegree on Docker"](https://github.com/lat-lon/deegree-workshop).